# Laravel 5: How to set parameters Response::json($data) as json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)?

Tags: php, json, laravel, unicode

Laravel 5: I have problem with unicode.
if I do

```
return Response::json(['data' => 'Что то']);
```

Receive {data: \u043e\u0431\u044c\u044f}

I want set parameter JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE to `Response::json()`

The following does not work:

```
Response::json(['data' => 'Что то'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Comment: if you are going to use it in blade then {!! $data !!}} gives you unescaped string.

Answer (score 0):

Set `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` as 4th parameter:

```
return Response::json(['data' => 'Что то'], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Glid it helped.